# When I run a python program using Process.Start the log in my python program does not work?

Tags: c#, python, logging, raspberry-pi, process.start

I'm running a python program from c# using `process.start()` on a raspberry pi zero w. I've tested it the program is running when called but it will not log to file. But if I just run the program myself `python Relays.py 0 0 0 0 0` the python log works. Does anyone know what is causing this problem?

Below are the python code and C# function:

```
void update()
        {
            String acommand = status();
            Console.WriteLine("LOOKSLIKEWEMADEIT " + acommand);
            String location = "/home/pi/Debug/Relays.py " + Convert.ToString(acommand);
            //run python 
            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("python", location);
            Process.Start(info);
            Console.WriteLine("YOUHAVEPASSEd");

        }

import RPi.GPIO as G
import time
import sys
import socket
import threading
import logging

G.setwarnings(False)
G.setmode(G.BOARD)

relays = (24,26,32,36,38)

for r in relays:
 G.setup(r,G.OUT)

logging.basicConfig(filename='Relaytrigger.log',level=logging.DEBUG,format='%(asctime)s %(message)s$

logging.info('\r\n')
logging.info(sys.argv)
logging.info('\r\n')

#######################heat
if sys.argv[1] == '1':
 heater = True
 G.output(relays[0],1)
 logging.info('heaton\r\n')
else:
 heater = False
 G.output(relays[0],0)
 logging.info('heatoff\r\n')
##########################main
if sys.argv[2] == '1':
 mainpump = True
 G.output(relays[1],1)
 logging.info('mainon\r\n')
else:
 mainpump = False
 G.output(relays[1],0)
 logging.info('mainoff\r\n')
#########################aux
if sys.argv[3] == '1':
 auxilarypump = True
 G.output(relays[2],1)
 logging.info('auxon\r\n')
else:
 auxilarypump = False
 G.output(relays[2],0)
 logging.info('auxoff\r\n')
#########################auxset
if sys.argv[4] == '1':
 auxsetting = True
 G.output(relays[3],1)
 logging.info('mainhigh\r\n')
else:
 auxsetting = False
 G.output(relays[3],0)
 logging.info('heatlow\r\n')
########################light
if sys.argv[5] == '1':
 lighting = True
 G.output(relays[4],1)
 logging.info('lighton\r\n')
else:
 lighting = False
 G.output(relays[4],0)
 logging.info('lightoff\r\n')
```

Comment: I'd think that the file is being created at another location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seems to me like problems with your CWD (current working directory).

Depending on from where an python application is started "relative paths" may differ.

Solution #1 : "The python-side solution":
Use absolute paths! Relative paths are more likely to be unsafe.

Solution #2 : "The C#-side solution":
Use the ProcessStartInfo-Property "WorkingDirectory" to define your CWD.
Your CWD is usualy the directory containing your .py file. 
[Link to ProcessStartInfo-Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)

HF

Comment: Thank you! I was saving the file in the wrong place and I just didn't realize it. I used an absolute path in the python and now the log is in the right place!